# Showing quadratic function with a positive definite matrix is bounded

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

So I have a quadratic function in the form: $f(x) = x^T A x + bx $ where A is a positive definite matrix and symmetric $ n\times n$ matrix and $q\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

So I know know that the function is strict convex and has a global minimum. Furthermore, all eigenvalues of the matrix are larger than zero. I can visualize how the matrix is bounded from below, but how can I proof this?

I tried to prove it using:

$$f(tx + (1-t)y) = tf(x) + (1-t)f(y)$$

But do not know how to incorporate the general form into this in order to prove it.

Comment: How can a (single) matrix be bounded (from below)? I am probably missing something

Comment: You can easily show that the function is coercive, therefore the level set is bounded

Comment: @TitoEliatron the matrix is part of a function representation. That function is bounded below

Comment: @mathguy69 I was, obviously, missing that. Thank's